# How can I write a perfect set as $c$ many pairwise disjoint perfect sets

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, transfinite-recursion, transfinite-induction

I have been thinking about this question but I have not get complete answer yet. the question is 
Let $P$ a nonempty  perfect subsets of $\mathbb R$ then $P$ can be written as continuum many pairwise disjoint  perfect sets. A partial answer that I got, if we restrict perfect set $P$ to nowhere dense set, then it will be totally disconnected. So $P$ and $P\times P$ are homeomorphic.
$P=\bigcup_{r\in P} (\{r\}\times P)$ as we need. My question is How about $P$ is not nowhere dense set, that is , it contains an open interval set. Any help will be useful.

Comment: Wasn't this question already answered in the comments to your previous question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3579429/ch-implies-omega-1-pairwise-disjoint-of-perfect-set

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti I was thinking if there is another way to do it.